# Accidentally rm'd Desktop folder, now Desktop doesn't appear visually

Tags: macos

So in my foolishness, I accidentally did `rm -rf` on my `~/Desktop` folder. Luckily nothing crucial was there anyways, so not worth shelling out a ton of cash for a professional to do data recovery.

However, I created a new `~/Desktop` folder, and it seems to have replaced the old one. The folder has the nice embossed logo on it:

[image]

Furthermore, whenever I take screenshots, they all end up in that folder. The folder even appears in the sidebar with a nice logo:

[image]

But, for some reason, none of the files in `~/Desktop` actually show up on my desktop.

On top of that, if I right-click on the desktop and select "New Folder" like so:

[image]

I get the following error:

[image]

How can I get my desktop working like normal?

Answer (score 0):

The fix was simple: relaunch finder.